# Resizing the bootstrap 3 header items without affecting the style for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, resize

I have changed the default bootstrap style by adding the margin and padding in my style.css but i want that the navigation would be at the left corner and not in the middle header side when i resize my browser screen to mobile size. How can i do it?

[image: Normal size]
[image: Mobile size]

Here is my index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Responsive Project (Prototype)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="mainHeader">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!--HEADER-->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand">A.M.®</a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!--BODY-->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Work Positions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!--USER OPTIONS-->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> Sign Up</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> Register</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: 150px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-header {
    padding-left: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries to only apply your styles to larger screens, like so:

```
body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav {
    font-weight: 600;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav {
        margin-left: 150px;
    }

    .navbar-header {
        padding-left: 150px;
    }
}
```